# Will the Collection view Cell size increase

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a collection view, which has one text view and label view down the text view.

if the text view got more text dynamically and the size of the text view increases, will the collection view cell size grow and the label move down automatically or i need to handle this manually. i am about to start a project and still in planning stage. i got this technical doubt.

Answer (score 0):

it will not increase actually, the text view will be enable to scroll to contain all the text

Comment: yes, but if i hide the text view and display it, there will be change in collection view cell size?